# How to build with profiling in Stack?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am struggling with building an app with profiling, because I need stack traces.

```
$ stack new prof 
$ cd prof
$ stack build --profile --executable-profiling --library-profiling 
$ stack exec prof-exe +RTS -p
stack: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof

$ stack --version
Version 2.7.1, Git revision 8afe0c2932716b0441cf4440d6942c59568b6b19 x86_64 hpack-0.34.4
```

ghc 8.10.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack itself is written in Haskell and therefore it accepts the `+RTS -p` parameter too. To pass the `+RTS -p` to your `prof-exe` you should use the `--` separator:

```
stack exec prof-exe -- +RTS -p
```

However, I believe the `run` command should be used for running executables, and I think you need to add the `--profile` flag there too. The command that works for me is:

```
stack run --profile prof-exe -- +RTS -p
```

Comment: run commands runs, but there is no stack trace I guess because dependency directory is not rebuild with profiling

Comment: I believe you need to also add [the `-xc` RTS option](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--xc) to get stack traces.